# Git when file is deleted from repo

Tags: git

I am looking to make a script to do the following.
I am assuming I am going to have to write a script
Here is what I need it to do.
If a file is deleted from the working copy of the repository, remove it (git rm) from the next commit.
Add all changes in the working copy to the next commit.

Comment: What you are describing/requesting is simply standard Git behavior.  When you delete a file, you can `git add` this change and then on the next commit the file will be removed from the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about articulating question helps me work it out.
Here is the answer.

```
git-stage-all(){
   if [ "`git ls-files -d | wc -l`" -gt "0" ]; then; git rm --quiet `git ls-files -d`; fi
   git add .
}
```

Comment: That'll work, but `git add -A` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`git add -u` will stage all changes to all tracked files.  This includes modifications and deletions.

`git add -A` will do the same thing, but it will also stage untracked files.